# Getting error in document.getElementsByName("xScoNum")[0].value , value is null or not an object

Tags: javascript

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Fri, 28 Mar 2014 04:23:31 UTC

Message: 'document.getElementsByName(...).0.value' is null or not an object
Line: 2963
Char: 1
Code: 0

Comment: You don't have any elements with the name you're using ?

Comment: what is your html code?

Comment: i am getting value from this syntax as well as error. :(. my HTML code is, <input id="xScoNum-5534" type="text" name="xScoNum" size="30" maxlength="30" value="44528-3" style="width: 0px; visibility: hidden;">

Comment: as per your comment thats not the proper usage of getElementsByTagName, see here:: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName(...).0.value' is null or not an object` usually occurs when you're trying to access an element that does not yet exist. The problem appears to be as JavaScript runs before the element is added. The element must be added to the DOM first, then you can access it.